# Set Kettle DB Connection password from Environment Variable

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

How do I set a database connection's password to use an environment variable. I cannot add these to the kettle.properties file (security policy). When I click control-space on OSX, nothing happens. If I try and paste the string `${PASSWORD}` directly into the password field, it does not allow it, due to the presumably non-alphanumeric `'$'` char.

The other fields as shown below work fine.

The **EDIT Connection** dialog below shows the field in red, which is what I want to achieve logically.

Using PDI Community 8.2, on Mac OSX Mojave.

[image: I want the field in red filled]

Answer (score 2):

I found one solution. Instead of creating the DB connection in **Table Input Step** with **Edit** or **New**, I used the **Wizard** option, which allowed me to paste ${SOURCE_DB_PASSWORD} variable into the password field.

The characters were obfuscated, so it's impossible to tell if you have the correct value, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+V doesn’t work, you need to right-click and choose paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the password and save it on kettle.properties, in spoon directory execute:

Encr.bat -kettle yourpassword

Paste the full result with "Encrypted" in the properties file, restart spoon and test the connection.

Comment: As per my original post, I cannot use the kettle.properties file for passwords.

Comment: even encrypted password?

Comment: Yes, All passwords are stored in a single Vault server and injected into each artefact (API, service, ETL job, etc) as required via ENV variables to EC2 instances, lambdas, etc in secured Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

In OSX, I believe you need to use the shortcut **shift + cmd + space** to access the environment variables.

You might need to use the **'get variables'**-step to define the variables from kettle.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just type ${Variable_Name} as you are defining for other environment variable. If open your .ktr file in Notepad++ you can see the value is your Variable_Name instead of Encrypted password. It worked for me :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggp9g.jpg)